# Create div with script tag inside with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, creation

I have content that I load dynamicaly with jquery. The content is HTML with a script tag in it.

So I have something like this.

```
var content = '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">alert("test");</script><div>mydiv</div>';
```

I want to create a new div with this content with jquery

```
var dialog = $('<div class="modal-popup">' + content + '</div>');
```

But in the new created div (dialog) there is no script tag.

In the past it worked. We updated jquery from 1.5.1 to 1.7.1. I already dowdated jquery, with the same result.

We use ist to create a print dialog and we recognized, that we can not print anymore. I am browsing through the repository, but can not find a change we have made.

What is the reason, the the script-tag is gone?

**EDIT:
It depends on the JQuery release. In v1.5.1 it works, in v1.7.2 not.**

The reason, that it does not work in my prior test with v1.5.1 was, that the browser cached jquery for some reasons

**EDIT 2: In this example content is a string variable to keep it simple. In real environment  content is filled by $.get and is an HTML-Document with javascript in it.**

Comment: With no further investigation, this sounds like a regression, or related to http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6516

Answer (score 0):

The `</` sequence of the closing `</script>` tag will end the parsing of the script element in HTML.

> You must never have the characters `</` anywhere inside your script
>   markup, even if it is part of a string. Browsers honoring HTML4 should stop the script block if this is seen -Phrogz

Escaping the slash `<\/` should solve the problem.

Comment: Specifically you must never have the characters `</` anywhere inside your script markup, even if it is part of a string. Browsers honoring HTML4 should stop the script block if this is seen.

Comment: Thanks for the post. But the example above was just to keep it simple. In real environment content ist filled bei $.get and is the response from an HTML-Document with javascript in it.